# testthat package 'label' parameter

Tags: r, parameters, label, testthat

I included a simple example of a test using the R package `testthat`,

```
testthat::expect_equal(1,0, label = 'First')
```

> Error: First not equal to 0.
>       1/1 mismatches
>       [1] 1 - 0 == 1

The label parameter replaces '1' by a word to give a more helpful error message. Now I'm interested in replacing the '0' as well. Such that we get something like

> Error: First not equal to Second.

I've tried this

```
testthat::expect_equal(1,0, label = c('First', 'Second'))
```

> Error in stop(exp) : bad error message

However this does not work as you may see.
I read the vignette on the package, but there's not a lot of info on this parameter.

Answer (score 4):

We can use

```
testthat::expect_equal(1,0, label = 'First', expected.label = 'Second')
```

> Error: First not equal to Second. 1/1 mismatches [1] 1 - 0 == 1

Answer (score 0):

It turned out to be quite simple.
The 'expected label' parameter is used for this.